# IBM MQ Explorer - create a Queue manager

Tags: ibm-mq

IBM's docs say:

1. Start WebSphere MQ Explorer.
2. In the Navigator view, right-click the Queue Managers folder, then click New > Queue Manager. The Create Queue Manager wizard opens.

Seems pretty simple. However, at step 2 I right click on Queue Managers and get a menu with:

- Show/Hide Queue Managers...
- Add Remote Queue Manager...
- Tests >
- Sets >

Any suggestion on how you create a new queue manager?

FWIW, I'm using `Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2`. And yes, I'm aware it's ancient. Out of my control unfortunately.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.explorer.doc/bi00256_.htm

Comment: Do you have a full MQ server installed on your machine or are you using the MQ Explorer from a MQ client install?  If the later you can not use it to create a queue manager, this is only available when you are running MQ Explorer on the same server as the MQ Server software is installed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the MQ Explorer will only show the create queue manager options if it can find the MQ JNI libraries it needs (via the PATH or LD_LIBRARY_PATH I guess).

It is totally valid to have MQ Explorer without the queue manager binaries installed (for example you can install a standalone MQ Explorer via MS0T), in which case you obviously couldnt create a queue manager.

So to start with, make sure you can issue commands like crtmqm on the machine, and secondly try setting up the PATH/LIBPATH to point into the MQ installation... ie from a shell/command prompt on windows try '\setmqenv -s' and on unix '. /setmqenv -s -k', and then launch explorer from that window.